# Nextflow use workflow.exitStatus in report scope at config file

Tags: workflow, nextflow

I'm trying to access workflow scope in the config file of Nextflow. In particular, I need the variable `workflow.exitStatus` if my pipeline fails to run, the report has the names `report_1.png` and `report_0.png` if it is successful.

This is the report scope in my config file:

```
report {
    enabled = true
    file = "out/report_${workflow.exitStatus}.html"
}
```

And I got an error:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.2
ERROR ~ Unknown config attribute `report.workflow.exitStatus` -- check config file: .../nextflow.config
```

Does anyone have any idea about using workflow scope in the config file? I'd be very appreciative if get any help, Thanks.